# How to optionally prevent/exclude an sqlalchemy relationship field from being loaded during Pydantic model validation

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pydantic-v2

I am using FastAPI with SQLAlchemy ORM and Pydantic models. I've encountered an issue where lazy-loaded ORM fields are inadvertently loaded by Pydantic's `model_validate` method. I want to exclude certain fields when loading a model using `model_validate`, particularly for cases where I need to prevent the loading of lazily loaded relationships.

With the release of Pydantic v2, is it possible to load a model and exclude certain fields when using the new `model_validate` method? I thought the `context` parameter might help, but it doesn't seem to do what I need.

Here's a simplified example of my code structure:

```py
# SQLAlchemy ORM model
class RoleOrm(OrmBase):
    __tablename__ = "roles"
    # Columns...
    role_permissions = relationship(..., lazy="joined")

# Pydantic model
class Role(BaseModel):
    # Fields...
    role_permissions: List[RolePermission] | None

# Repository
class RoleRepository:
    @staticmethod
    async def get_by_uid(db: AsyncSession, uid: str) -> Role:
        statement = select(RoleOrm).where(RoleOrm.uid == uid)
        results = await db.execute(statement)
        role_orm = results.unique().scalar_one_or_none()
        if not role_orm:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=404,
                detail="Role with given id does not exist",
            )
        role = Role.model_validate(role_orm)
        return role

    @staticmethod
    async def get_many(
        db: AsyncSession, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 20
    ) -> tuple[list[Role], str]:
        count = await db.scalar(select(func.count(RoleOrm.uid)))
        if not count:
            return [], "0"
        statement = (
            select(RoleOrm)
            .offset(skip)
            .limit(limit)
        )
        results = await db.execute(statement)
        roles = [Role.model_validate(orm) for orm in results.unique().scalars().all()]
        return roles, str(count)
```

In get_many, I want to avoid loading `role_permissions`, but in `get_by_uid`, I need them included. How can I achieve this selective field exclusion in Pydantic's `model_validate`?

Related GitHub issues:

1. [model_validate: exclude #8192](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/8192)
2. [ORM models and lazy loading. How to optionally prevent a field from being loaded?](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/4508)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it by using SQLAlchemy's `noload` to explicitly prevent the loading of relationships in certain queries. This approach allows you to control relationship loading in your repository methods.

Here's how I modified the repository to handle this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import noload

class RoleRepository:
    # Method to get a single role with permissions
    @staticmethod
    async def get_by_uid(db: AsyncSession, uid: str) -> Role:
        statement = select(RoleOrm).where(RoleOrm.uid == uid)
        role_orm = await db.execute(statement).scalar_one_or_none()
        if not role_orm:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Role not found")
        return Role.model_validate(role_orm)

    # Method to get multiple roles without permissions
    @staticmethod
    async def get_many(db: AsyncSession, skip: int, limit: int) -> tuple[list[Role], str]:
        count = await db.scalar(select(func.count(RoleOrm.uid)))
        statement = (
            select(RoleOrm)
            .options(noload(RoleOrm.role_permissions))
            .offset(skip)
            .limit(limit)
        )
        roles = [Role.model_validate(orm) for orm in await db.execute(statement).scalars().all()]
        return roles, str(count)
```